# Visual Studio C# and Short-circuit evaluation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With the || Operator, Microsoft describes  short circuit evaluation here [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator)

However, I have the following code which seems to contradict this process:

```
  if ((_opcLoaded || DoLoadOPC()) &&
     (_tagsAdded || DoAddTags()) &&
     DoWriteRecipe() && 
     (DoResume()))
```

What I'm trying to prevent is the function DoAddTags from being called if _tagsAdded is true (DoAddTags sets _tagsAdded to true).

However, I'm finding that `DoAddTag`s is called even when `_tagsAdded` is true. It's the same for `_opcLoaded` and `DoLoadOPC`. I've had to put a condition inside `DoAddTags` to check for `_tagsAdded`, which shouldn't be necessary.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here is the Complete Code

```
    //
                        // Resume a Paused recipe
                    case MonitoredTasks.Resume:
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {
                                MonitoredTask = MonitoredTasks.None;
                                if ((_opcLoaded || DoLoadOPC()) &&
                                      **(_tagsAdded || DoAddTags())** &&
                                      DoWriteRecipe() && 
                                      (DoResume()))
                                {
                                    MonitoredTask = MonitoredTasks.None;
                                    RunningState = RecipeRunningStates.Running;
                                    Status = CIPStatuses.Running;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MonitoredTask = MonitoredTasks.Resume;
                                }
                            });

                        break;
```

And the code for DoAddTags

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Adds all necessary tags to the OPC Server Manager
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool DoAddTags()
    {

        bool result = false;
        var oldActivity = Activity;
        //
        // Not doing anything OPC related?
        if (Activity != CIPActivities.AddingOPCTags && !_tagsAdded && Activity != CIPActivities.StartingOPC)
        {
            lock (_locks[LOCK_OPC])
            { 
                Activity = CIPActivities.AddingOPCTags;
                Status = CIPStatuses.Initialising;
                RecipeError = Errors.None;
                try
                {
                    //
                    // Reset connection and internal tags list
                    _serverManager.Reset();

                    //
                    // Now to add all OPC Tags - Area
                    CIPStatusTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.CIPStatusTag);
                    RecipeIDTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.RecipeIDTag);
                    RecipeInstructionIDTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.RecipeInstructionIDTag);
                    HandshakingTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.HandshakingTag);
                    GlobalInstructionIDTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.GlobalInstructionIDTag);
                    InstructionAttemptsTag = _serverManager.AddTag(_area.InstructionAttemptsTag);

                    //
                    // Area tags OK?
                    if (CIPStatusTag == null || RecipeIDTag == null || RecipeInstructionIDTag == null || HandshakingTag == null || GlobalInstructionIDTag == null || InstructionAttemptsTag == null)
                    {
                        RecipeError = Errors.InvalidAreaTags;
                        DoError(new RecipeErrorHandlerEventArgs(this) { Message = FormatMessage("CIPRecipe.DoAddTags - Invalid AREA Tags"), Sender = this });
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        VM_CIPInstruction vm = null;
                        bool instructionTagErrors = false;
                        //
                        // For each area instruction that is used, assig a link to the instruction
                        foreach (var i in _areaInstructions)
                        {
                            //
                            // Create a View Model for the specified area instruction : this allows us to determine the number of parameters (tags) that apply to the instruction
                            vm = new VM_CIPInstruction(i.Value.Instruction);
                            //
                            // Assign device reference tags
                            if (vm.DeviceReferencesAvailable)
                            {
                                i.Value.DeviceTag = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.DeviceReferenceTag);
                                instructionTagErrors = i.Value.DeviceTag == null;
                            }
                            //
                            // For  each required parameter, add tag
                            for (int paramNo = 1; paramNo <= vm.NoOfParams; paramNo++)
                            {
                                switch (paramNo)
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it 
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param1Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param1 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param1Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param1 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it 
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param2Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param2 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param2Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param2 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it 
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param3Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param3 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param3Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param3 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it and then check quality
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param4Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param4 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param4Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param4 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case 5:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it and then check quality
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param5Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param5 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param5Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param5 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case 6:
                                        //
                                        // Tag defined? Add it and then check quality
                                        if (vm.AreaInstruction.Param6Tag >= 0)
                                        {
                                            i.Value.Param6 = _serverManager.AddTag(i.Value.Instruction.Param6Tag);

                                            if (i.Value.Param6 == null)
                                            {
                                                instructionTagErrors = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            instructionTagErrors = true;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (instructionTagErrors)
                            {
                                RecipeError = Errors.InvalidInstructionTags;
                                DoError(new RecipeErrorHandlerEventArgs(this) { Message = FormatMessage(String.Format("CIPRecipe.DoAddTags - Invalid Instruction {0} Tags", vm.Name)), Sender = this });
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //
                        // Any problems adding tags?
                        if (RecipeError == Errors.None)
                        {
                            Activity = CIPActivities.StartingOPC;
                            //
                            // Once all tags added, start OPC Server
                            result = _serverManager.Start();

                            if (!result)
                            {
                                Status = CIPStatuses.AddTagsFailed;
                                RecipeError = Errors.OPC;
                                DoError(new RecipeErrorHandlerEventArgs(this) { Message = FormatMessage("CIPRecipe.DoAddTags - Start of OPC failed"), Sender = this });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                **_tagsAdded = true;**
                                Status = CIPStatuses.TagsAdded;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Status = CIPStatuses.AddTagsFailed;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    RecipeError = Errors.Exception_AddTags;
                    DoError(new RecipeErrorHandlerEventArgs(this) { Message = FormatMessage("CIPRecipe.DoAddTags"), Exception = ex, Sender = this });
                }
                finally
                {
                    Activity = oldActivity;
                }
            }
        }
        return Status == CIPStatuses.TagsAdded;
    }
```

I've highlighted the relevant lines with **

On the first pass DoAddTags is executed and _tagsAdded set to TRUE- I've placed a breakpoint here, so I know it is being set. Shortly afterwards (with or without the former breakpoint) DoAddTags is again entered (on the first line) despite_doAddTags == true.

I've even set a breakpoint on the code "**(_tagsAdded || DoAddTags())**". _tagsAdded == true, yet DoAddTags is still entered.

So what I'm seeing is, and all the Watches/Debugging info is consistent with is that DoAddTags is being called whilst _tagsAdded == true

Comment: Pretty hard to unravel the possible side-effects of this expression.  Just don't write unreadable code, this requires more if-statements.

Comment: Cannot reproduce behavior specified in your question. Are you sure that these fields are not set to false before?

Comment: Are you sure DoAddTags is called? Maybe it is called from other place. I have checked in Debug and DoAddTags is not called if _tagsAdded is true. Place a brakepoint inside DoAddTags and check if _tagsAdded  is true. If so check CallStack if it is called from place you expect.

Comment: @m.rogalski - DoAddTags is only called from the expression listed.. which is supported  by looking at the stack. Even placing a breakpoint on "_tagsAdded || DoAddTags()", DoAddTags is entered when "_tagsAdded == true"

Answer (score 2):

This code won't display the behavior you describe, the short-circuiting works just as described.

What actually happens: `_tagsAdded` is initially `false`, so `DoAddTags()` is called, which sets `_tagsAdded` to `true`.

Then the debugger kicks in, you inspect `_tagsAdded` and see it's `true`.

Instead step through your code using F11 and inspect or watch all relevant variables.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong.

1 - I have a breakpoint on the entry DoAddTags.

2 - I have a Watch on _tagsAdded

3 - When the breakpoint is hit a second time, _doAddTags is true. i.e. the function has been entered despite the short circuit.

4 - All developers (20+) in my department cannot explain the behaviour.

Comment: if (Activity != CIPActivities.AddingOPCTags && !_tagsAdded)

This is the first line in DoAddTags. 

_tagsAdded, on the second reiteration is TRUE. Short circuit has not been applied otherwise this code would not have been called

Comment: No, I'm not wrong. [See this Ideone](http://ideone.com/M5GXNP). I'm working off of what you gave us. If you don't provide a [mcve], this answer is as close as it's going to get. You either have some threading issues, or the debugger is lying to you, or any of many other problems. Perhaps add some logging to record the values at certain points in your program.